# Python how to plot one subplot for each day in a time series? Convert datetime to time on x-axis

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, seaborn

My data is as follows:

```
date                   value
2022-03-13 19:00:03    116
2022-03-13 19:05:02    114
2022-03-13 19:10:02    112
2022-03-13 19:15:02    111
2022-03-13 19:20:02    110
```

Where `date` is datetime64[ns]. The data is over a multi-day period (e.g. 30 days), and **I want to generate a plot that has one subplot for each day**, such that if the dataset contains 30 days worth of data there would be 30 subplots arranged in rows and columns, with one plot for each day, and each individual x-axis ranging from 0-24 hours.

Desired output:
[image]

**The Problem:**

I cannot figure out what to do with my datetime values to make them plot nicely using matplotlib/seaborn. My idea was to use a seaborn relplot or facetgrid where `col='day'` after generating new columns as follows:

```
df['day'] = df['date'].dt.date
df['time'] = df['date'].dt.time
```

Which yields this:

```
date                    value   day           time
2022-03-13 19:00:03     116     2022-03-13    19:00:03
2022-03-13 19:05:02     114     2022-03-13    19:05:02
2022-03-13 19:10:02     112     2022-03-13    19:10:02
2022-03-13 19:15:02     111     2022-03-13    19:15:02
2022-03-13 19:20:02     110     2022-03-13    19:20:02
```

If I use `date` as the x-value:

```
sns.relplot(data=df, x='date', y='bgl', col='day')
```

The output is something like this:
[image]

Which is headed in the right direction, but clearly since the x-axis is `datetime` it is treating the x-axis for each subplot as the total time range of the dataset.

Using `x=time` instead:

```
sns.relplot(data=df, x='time', y='bgl', col='day')
```

Gives me an error: `float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'datetime.time'`

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Maybe `sns.relplot(...., sharex=False)`?

Comment: @JohanC unfortunately it looks like `sharex` is not a valid property (`AttributeError: 'PathCollection' object has no property 'sharex'`)

Comment: And what about `sns.relplot(...., facet_kws={'sharex':False})`?

Comment: @JohanC that yields another error, akin to the one in my OP: `TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'datetime.time'`

Comment: `sns.relplot(data=df, x='date', y='bgl', col='day',  facet_kws={'sharex':False})` gives you that error?

Comment: @JohanC Aha! I must have had some typo in my code the first time you suggested that.. Honestly not sure what happened since it was a few days ago. But your last suggestion did in fact work. Thank you very much!!